# GAP routine for computing orbits of cosets.

Tags: finite-groups, gap, computational-algebra

Let $G=N{.}Q$ be an extension with N nonabelian.  I act $N$ on the coset $Ng$, g is a lifting for a class representative $q \in Q$, to get say $l$ orbits. Now I act the centralizer $C_Q(q)$ on the set of $l$ orbits to get say $t$ orbits. How do I write a GAP routine to find these orbits. The action is by conjugation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you want. Are you asking for the orbits of the full pre-image of the centralizer of $Ng$ in $G/N$ on the elements of the coset $Ng$? Or do you care about the values of your $l$ and $t$?

Comment: I am mostly interesting in the orbits of the full pre-image of the centralizer of Ng in G/N on the elements of the coset Ng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to write down how the action happens. Let $ng\in Ng$, and $c\in G$ such that $Nc\in C_{G/N}(g)$. Then
$$
(ng)^c=n^cg^c=n^c c^{-1} g c g^{-1} g= \left(n^c [c,g^{-1}]\right) g
$$

So that is the action we need to implement. It probably is easiest to represent coset elements by their $N$-part. Then, one can implement this action as follows, using the above formula. Assume that `g` is already defined as representative. Then define

```
OngCosetElems:=function(n,c)
  return n^c*Comm(c,Inverse(g));
end;
```

and for example (here the centralizer preimage is the whole group):

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(5);;N:=DerivedSubgroup(G);
Alt( [ 1 .. 5 ] )
gap> g:=(1,2);;
gap> e:=Elements(N);;
gap> o:=OrbitsDomain(G,e,OngCosetElems);
[ [ (), (1,2,3), (1,2)(3,4), (1,3,2), (1,2)(4,5), (1,2,4), (1,5,2),(1,2)(3,5), (1,4,2), (1,2,5) ],
  [ (3,4,5), (1,4,5,2,3), (2,5)(3,4), (1,3,2,4,5), (2,3)(4,5), (1,5)(3,4),(1,3,5,2,4), (1,5,2,3,4), (1,3)(4,5), (2,4)(3,5), (1,4,2,3,5),(1,3,4,2,5), (1,5,2,4,3), (1,4)(3,5), (3,5,4), (1,4,3,2,5),(1,4,2,5,3), (1,5,4,2,3), (1,3,2,5,4), (1,5,3,2,4) ],
  [ (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4,5), (1,3,4), (1,3,4,5,2), (1,2,4,5,3), (2,4,5),(1,4,3,5,2), (1,4,5,3,2), (2,3,5), (1,4,5), (2,5,4), (1,2,4,3,5), (1,4)(2,5), (1,3,5), (1,3)(2,5), (1,5)(2,3), (1,5,4), (1,3,5,4,2),(2,5,3), (1,5)(2,4), (1,3)(2,4), (2,4,3), (1,5,3), (1,2,3,5,4),(1,4)(2,3), (1,4,3), (1,5,3,4,2), (1,2,5,3,4), (1,2,5,4,3),(1,5,4,3,2) ] ]
gap> List(o,Length);
[ 10, 20, 30 ]
```

Instead of using a global variable for `g` you might find it convenient to create the action function by a function. We also cache $g^{-1}$:

```
CosetActFunctionCreator:=function(g)
local gi;
  gi:=Inverse(g);
  return function(n,c)
    return n^c*Comm(c,gi);
  end;
end;
```

and then use:

```
gap> o:=OrbitsDomain(G,e,CosetActFunctionCreator(g));
```

Of course in the orbit algorithm, always the same few elements `c` act, and one could thus cache the commutators. Furthermore, it would be helpful for performance to consider $N$-orbits first, but this quickly gets more difficult.

Comment: I tested the algorithm on the maximal subgroup $3^2{:}2S4$ of $M_{12}$ and it seems like it fails if $g$ is a nontrivial element. It works if $g$ is trivial. Perhaps I am overlooking something.

Comment: What do you mean by "It fails"?

Comment: This GAP line " o:=OrbitsDomain(G,e,OngCosetElems);" does not give me an answer.  Please can you perhaps verify the algorithm for the group $3^2{:}2S_4$.

Comment: This is what I did in GAP with the maximal subgroup $3^2{:}2S_4$  gap>G:=Group(output[1],output[2]);
<matrix group with 2 generators>
gap> N:=Nor[1];
<matrix group of size 9 with 2 generators>
gap> con:=ConjugacyClasses(G);
gap> g:=Representative(con[2]);
gap> OngCosetElems:=function(n,c)
>   return n^c*Comm(c,Inverse(g));
> end;
function( n, c ) ... end
gap> e:=Elements(N);;
gap> o:=OrbitsDomain(G,e,OngCosetElems);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `[]' on 2 arguments
The 2nd argument is 'fail'

Comment: I think this error is an issue with matrix groups. Try it in a permutation representation and if you want send a *fully reproducable* example (showing how you created the objects) of the error to the support@gap-system.org email list.